# Why is it important to eliminate ground-shift at the ground of a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, ground, current-measurement, shunt, dc-offset

I've asked a question about differential amplifiers and their uses in measuring current through a shunt.

In doing so, lots of people advised me not to sense current on the low-side since that can inject offset and cause a ground-shift at the micro-controller's ground.

What exactly is ground-shift and what are the potential problems it can cause (especially in regards of ADC measurements) in addition to the common methods used to deal with it?

Also, is it related to ground bounce in logic gates?

Comment: When You got a shunt, the current passing through it will create a voltage drop - right? And when You have it on the low side, You apparently create a potencial difference between source and load ground. And when a microcontroller wants to measure some voltage on the load, the result will be offseted by the voltage on the shunt.

Comment: Ground shifting just meant you to look at the ground wiring is not 0 ohm, but has some impedance (dependency to frequency as well). When current flows, it develops voltage.
As long as you keep the shunt away from any other significant current (return current, including the driver) than the signal (load current), shunt on ground is ok. High-side measurement needs as much caution as the low-side (ground side). It is just a matter of wiring and arrangement/placement of devices.risk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what voltage is, or how it is defined. Voltage is the difference of two potentials in space (e.g. on a circuit board).

If your ADC is connected to GND_1 and measures V_1 it actually measures the difference between V_1 and GND_1. If lets say you measure the current draw of a second controller by connecting it's ground GND_2 to a shunt (GND_2 -> R -> GND_1) an measure the voltage drop across the shunt you are (by ohms law U=RI) introducing a voltage difference between GND_1 and GND_2.

This means: if your controller is connected to V_1 and measures its own supply voltage it will return (V_1-GND_1)-(GND_2-GND_1) or the difference between V_1 and GND_2 which is different (by U=R_Shunt*I_Draw) to V_1 - GND_1.

This can have certain side effects!

1. In ADC measurements it introduces an offset - you can compensate this by computation though. But this tends to get messy - and you never know where these effects are present.
2. In digital circuits the problem can be much worse. Say you have controller 1 and 2 wich are interconnected through digital pins. They are referenced to different GND's with a difference in voltage. If you pull both sides low there will be a high current flow through the controllers because you connected a voltage difference through a low impedance line.
3. If you limit this current surge with e.g. a series resistor, there is also the risk of violating your signal conditions. Imagine controller A and B connected through a 100m wire. Controller B is supplied through this cable too - this effectively introduces a voltage shift. Now Controller A gives a Signal with 3V3 level to B-side. But B side only 'sees' 2V5 and does not recognise this as high level.
   And this stuff is nasty to troubleshoot!  To solve this you can use differential transmission, wehereby not only the signal, but also its reference is carried from A to B.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation that all the ground points in your circuit are at the same potential. The reality can be somewhat different do to resistance in the gnd wiring and the flow of current.

Ground bounce is when the gnd of a logic gate rises due to switching currents and this causes the voltage the input sees to differ from the level of the device that sent it. This can cause a wrong logic level to be interpreted.

Similarly with analog circuits you can have the same effect. Due to differing gnd potentials, what the receiving analog device sees is different to what sent it.

Imagine a road that should be nominally flat, but due to ground disturbance (earthquake) there is a step.thus the height (voltage) at point A is different to point B.

Answer (score 1):

> In doing so, lots of people advised me not to sense current on the
> low-side since that can inject offset and cause a ground-shift at the
> micro-controller's ground.

Some floating, regulated DC supplies have extra terminals beside the usual two **output terminals**. These extras are used to feed back voltage to the power supply regulator. The four terminals might be labelled:

- +Vout
- -Vout
- +Vsense
- -Vsense

In such a supply, it is possible to insert a current-sensing resistor (one ohm in this example) in the "ground" side of the supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK6FwZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The DC supply must be a floating one with no other connections to **-Vout**. It is assumed that input resistance of the ADC is far higher than the value of current sense resistor. It is best to put this current-sense resistor inside the Target device, so that its GND-side is well established.

The voltage developed across the current sense resistor subtracts from the headroom of the DC supply, so it is unwise to use a large value here, especially if current asked by the Target is near the supply's upper limit. Better to use a low ADC reference voltage, or use an internal ADC preamp if one is available.

Note that the ADC will see a negative-going input while current flows. Many ADCs won't like this, and will require a positive offset (not shown here).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBcLr5.png)</sup>

Even a standard 3-terminal voltage regulator can be used (7805, above). However, be aware that internal currents in its ***GND*** terminal vary with input voltage changes, and also vary a bit with output current (by a fraction of a milliamp), affecting linear current sensing somewhat.
Again, ADC will have to deal with a negative-going input voltage.